# WebRequest between ASP.NET MVC Webs on the same server always not authorized (401)

Tags: windows, authentication, webrequest

I have two Webs, one ASP.NET MVC Core 2 and one ASP.NET MVC 5 both with windows authentication on the same server (IIS). Each web works perfect also the windows authentication. Now I have the need to call actions in the core web from the MVC 5 web like this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(source);
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        MemoryStream dataStream = new MemoryStream();
        response.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(dataStream);
```

the problem is that I always get the not authorized (401) error - if a call the action from the browser it works but not with WebRequest...

in ASP.NET MVC 5 I have set windows authentication and 
in ASP.NET MVC Core  have set windows authentication and all works except the call from WebRequest...

any ideas whats the Problem?

**as a side node: if I set the credentials like this it works but I don't need a fix account but the current logged on user**

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
```

robert

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771992/how-do-i-call-an-mvc-action-via-a-webrequest-and-validate-the-request-through-ac

Comment: no this seems not to be the Problem - if I use identity.Impersonate() it doesn't also work:
WindowsIdentity identity = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;
using (identity.Impersonate())
  {
  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(source);
                request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                request.PreAuthenticate = true;
                request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
 }

Comment: as another side node: this is working in Development Environment with IISExpress but not in IIS...

any other ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: I solved it by adding the webserver in AD to the allow Delegation...